# How can I make AJAX requests using the Express framework?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I want to send AJAX requests using Express. I am running code that looks like the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   // here I would like to make an external
   // request to another server
});

app.listen(3000);
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need Express to make an outgoing HTTP request. Use the native module for that:

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'example.com',
  port: '80',
  path: '/path',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': post_data.length
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
  // response is here
});

// write the request parameters
req.write('post=data&is=specified&like=this');
req.end();
```

Comment: Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

Answer (score 37):

You can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://localhost:6000', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the body of response.
  }
})
```

Answer (score 15):

Since you are simply making a get request I suggest this
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback

```
var http = require('http');

http.get("http://www.google.com/index.html", function(res) {

  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);

  if(res.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Got value: " + res.statusMessage);
  }

}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);

});
```

That code is from that link

Comment: Much easier than the top answer!